# How to POST model in Java Spring with non-primitive field [Not Enum]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to do post on my model Knight. It has field Weapon [custom class]. I am using thymeleaf SELECT element with bootstrap. It gives me error about wrong type [it gets String but should get Weapon]. I've found info how to use ENUMS but I have custom type [Weapon].

If I make new constructor in Weapon class it works but It adds new sort of weapon, not using the existing one. I am not using DB. Repos holds all in ArrayList

The error I am getting:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.severinu.springpodstawy.domain.Weapon for property weapon; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type com.severinu.springpodstawy.domain.Weapon for property weapon: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

```
public class Knight {

    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message = "{name.notnull}")
    @NotEmpty(message = "{name.required}")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50 , message = "{name.length} 3-50  {characters}")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "{age.notnull}")
    @Min(value = 15, message = "{age.min} 15")
    @Max(value = 100, message = "{age.max} 100")
    private Integer age;

    private int level = 1;
    private int energy = 1000;
    private Weapon weapon;
    private Armour armour;

    private Quest quest;
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping
    public String saveKnight(@ModelAttribute("knight") Knight knight,
                             BindingResult result,
                             Model model) {

        System.out.println(result);
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            // set random weapon on level 1 to the knight
            knightService.assignRandomWeapon(knight, 1);
            // set random armour on level 1 to the knight
            knightService.assignRandomArmour(knight,1);
            System.out.println(knight);
            knightService.saveKnight(knight);
        } else {
            // form has error, display form again
            return "knightform";
        }
        // no errors, redirect to knight list
        return "redirect:knights";
    }
@GetMapping("/add")
    public String addKnightForm(Model model) {
        List<Weapon> weaponsOnLevel1 =  weaponService.getAllWeaponsOnLevel(1);
        model.addAttribute("knight", new Knight());
        model.addAttribute("weapons", weaponsOnLevel1);
        model.addAttribute("weapon", new Weapon()); // ??
        return "knightform";
    }
```

Form

```
<form th:object="${knight}" th:action="@{/knights}" th:method="post" >
                <!-- form errors -->
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}" class="form-errors-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.allErrors()}" th:text="${err}" />
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /end form errors -->
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label th:text="${#strings.capitalize('__#{knight.name}__') + ':'}" for="knightName" class="form-label">Knight name:</label>
                    <input th:field="*{name}"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="knightName"
                           th:placeholder="${#strings.capitalize('__#{knight.form.placeholder.addname}__')}"
                    />
                    <p class="form-text col-auto form-field-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}">Niepoprawne imię rycerza </p>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label  th:text="${#strings.capitalize('__#{knight.age}__') + ':'}"
                            for="knightAge"
                            class="form-label col-auto">Age:</label>
                    <input th:field="*{age}"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="knightAge"
                           th:placeholder="${#strings.capitalize('__#{knight.form.placeholder.addage}__')}"
                    />
                    <p class="form-text col-auto form-field-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}">Niepoprawny wiek rycerza </p>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <select th:field="*{weapon}" class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect03" >
                        <option th:each="weapon: ${weapons}"
                                th:text="${weapon.getName()}"
                                th:value="${weapon}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button th:text="${#strings.capitalize('__#{knight.add}__')}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Knight</button>

            </form>
```

Weapon class

```
public class Weapon {

    protected Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int damage;
    private int strength;
    private int level = 1;

    public Weapon() { }

    public Weapon(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Weapon(Integer id, String name, int level, int damage, int strength) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Weapon(String name, int damage, int strength) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public Weapon(String name, int level, int damage, int strength) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public void setDamage(int damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        return "Weapon: " + name + ", damage: " + damage + ", strength: " + strength;
//    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Weapon weapon = (Weapon) o;
        return damage == weapon.damage && strength == weapon.strength && level == weapon.level && Objects.equals(id, weapon.id) && Objects.equals(name, weapon.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, damage, strength, level);
    }
}
```

Weapons repo ...

```
@Repository
public class WeaponsInMemoryRepository implements WeaponRepository {

    private List<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<Weapon> getAllWeapons() {
        return weapons;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Weapon> getAllWeaponsOnLevel(int level) {
        return weapons.stream()
                .filter(weapon -> weapon.getLevel() == level)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
...
...
```

Weapons service ...

```
@Service
public class WeaponService {

    private final WeaponRepository weaponRepository;

    public WeaponService(WeaponRepository weaponRepository) {
        this.weaponRepository = weaponRepository;
    }

    public List<Weapon> getAllWeapons() {
        return new ArrayList<>(weaponRepository.getAllWeapons());
    }

    public void saveWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        weaponRepository.addWeapon(weapon);
    }
...
...
```

Comment: Write a converter for `String` to `Weapon` and vice-versa. Register that with the conversion service and it will be used to convert the `String` to a `Weapon`.

Comment: somehow didn't worked, maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Instead of writing a converter, you can also use the `id` of the Weapon in the `<select>`. See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/16/using-html-select-options-with-thymeleaf/ for details on how to do that.

Comment: I guess it may work if there is some sort of relation one to one , one to may [etc] with the usage of DB. I am not using DB. Just ArrayList or Map.

Comment: Made it. Had to create couple custom types converters. I am passing ID of the custom type and converter is using service to find given item in my repositiry [ArrayList].